# DB2 Dialect instead of H2Dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have in my YML this JPA configurations.

```
   jpa:
      database-platform: DB2Platform
      ddl-auto: create-drop
      hibernate:
         properties:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

But when a run the app it fails because is reading a H2Dialect:

```
2020-03-10 11:11:07.980  INFO PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : --- HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2020-03-10 11:11:08.076  INFO PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : --- HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-03-10 11:11:08.503  INFO PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : --- HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-03-10 11:11:09.692  INFO PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : --- HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-03-10 11:11:10.187  INFO PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] o.h.validator.internal.util.Version      : --- HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.14.Final
2020-03-10 11:11:10.552  INFO PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : --- HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@14911c1'
2020-03-10 11:11:10.639  INFO PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : --- Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-10 11:11:10.759  WARN PID_IS_UNDEFINED [           main] o.s.c.support.GenericApplicationContext  : --- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/0016162/Documents/Workspace/api-arranques-vep/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO T6032500 (CEMPRESA, CMONPAGO, DMONPAGO, XMONFUNC, XPERENCU, XCOMPUTA, XBONISRV) VALUES('01', '001', 'FPP', '6', '1', '0', '1'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Tabla "T6032500" no encontrada
```

I'm using the Spring version 2.1.3

I add the DB configuration:

```
spring:
   profiles: ******
   datasource:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:db2://ds81wszs.pre.geci:#####/DS81
      username: ********
      password: ********
      driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
      testWhileIdle: true
      continueOnError: true
      connectionTestQuery: select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1
      autoCommit: true
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      idleTimeout: 600000
      maxLifetime: 1800000
      minimumIdle: 10
      maximumPoolSize: 10
      initializationFailTimeout: 1
      isolateInternalQueries: false
      allowPoolSuspension: false
      readOnly: false
      registerMbeans: false
      transactionIsolation: TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
      validationTimeout: 5000
      leakDetectionThreshold: 0
   jpa:
     database-platform: DB2Platform
     properties:
       hibernate:
         dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

I have hidden the connection data.

Comment: Hi, could you post the url conifg of your db url

Comment: Hi, I added the config information

Comment: the error comes from the excution of data.sql , it tries to insert in a table (T6032500 ) that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are try to import some data at startup, and the same time there is a `data.sql` that has import into a table `T6032500`, so this import causes the exception due to non existing table ( drop ddl auto )

try to create a `schema.sql` put it with the `data.sql` file 
and then set the jpa ddl-auto propertie to

I have in my YML this JPA configurations.

```
spring:
    jpa:
       ddl-auto: none
       hibernate:
         ddl-auto:none
```

the `schema.sql` could look like :

```
CREATE TABLE T6032500 (
    CEMPRESA VARCHAR(5),
    ...
    ...
);
```